# How do i make a Discord like login form?

Tags: html, css, forms, authentication, discord

How do I make a login form like the one on discord's login page. I have made till here. But I don't know what to do after that. Please help (You can view the full snippet in the link below):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/waves.css">
</head>
<body>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div id='stars'></div>
<div id='stars2'></div>
<div id='stars3'></div>
<div id='title'>
  <span>

  </span>
  <br>
  <span>

  </span>
</div>
<script src="waves.js">
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/shree-krishna/pen/wveKVJV

I have made a copy of the code and posted in  codepen.io because the code is too long to be posted here. I have made the discord-like waves but I also tried to make a login form on those waves but this happened:

[image: I have also changed the z-index of the login form and the waves but nothing happened to the result.]

please note that the subtle bubbles in the black area of the waves also disappeared